# Knockout.JS: Triggers based on changes in an observable

Tags: triggers, knockout.js, observable

I have an input element which is bound to a knockout observable:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myText, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```

This updates the observable on each keyup. I now want to trigger additional events when the value changes.

The following does this in principle:

```
this.myTextTrigger = ko.computed( function () {
    console.log( this.myText() );
}, this );
```

However, it seems somewhat clunky. It also triggers on the initial instantiation of the template, where I only want to handle changes after that.
Is there an official/easier way to trigger events based on changes to observables?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use subscribe:

```
this.myText.subscribe(function (newText) {
   console.log(newText);
});
```

If you want to reuse this trigger you can consider writting a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: +1 for manual subscriptions (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables)

Comment: A custom binding seems like overkill for a single input IMHO. A subscription sounds like a better choice to me.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! - Regarding the custom bindings: Is there a way to have generalized binding for fields where changes are supposed to trigger other events, and pass this the function to execute from within the binding in the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get extra information in your binding then use `allBindings.get(`*`nameOfOtherBinding`*`)` and set the **`nameOfOtherBinding`** parameter to refer to the name of the binding in that element which is pointing to a function. Either put the function literal in the HTML or make sure you can find that function in scope of the handlers definition (like globally attached to the `window` object).

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

[JS Fiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/pqb4xubg/](http://jsfiddle.net/pqb4xubg/)

The javascript that would set up the handler(either in *init* or *update*):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.generic = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings){
        var val = 'nothing';
        // set your other bindings to get pulled in
        var func = allBindings.get('func');
        // normal check if the binding is actually a function
        if(typeof func === 'function'){
            // use the retrieved function
            val = func(valueAccessor());
        }
        element.innerText = val;
    }
};
var model = {a:'4', b:5};
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The html that would use the handler (notice how the elements with the "fun" binding do not work):

```
<div data-bind="generic: a, func: function( val ){ return val + 2; }"></div>
<div data-bind="generic: a, fun: function( val ){ return val + 2; }"></div>
<div data-bind="text: a"></div>
<div data-bind="generic: b, func: function( val ){ return val + 2; }"></div>
<div data-bind="generic: b, fun: function( val ){ return val + 2; }"></div>
<div data-bind="text: b"></div>
```

You can also just use the init of the bind to setup standard DOM event handlers and just explicitly call those functions using something like jQuery. Thank you. Good day.